# Chrome in incognito mode will not download video file until finish streaming

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, jwplayer

We're building a website which let you watch (stream) online video and the option to download the video file as well.

We use jwplayer in html5 mode to play the video.

We see different behavior when using Chrome in regular mode vs. incognito mode when trying to download the file while streaming.

In regular mode, it is possible to download the file simultaneously while playing the video.

In incognito mode, we see that the download request is pending until the previous request for streaming is finish. results in longs seconds where nothing happening on screen until the download suddenly start.

What is causing the change in behaviour?

**UPDATE**

To enable download functionality, we use hidden iframe

```
<iframe id="download-iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

and the "download" button click handler set the iframe's url:

```
document.getElementById('download-iframe').src = "video url...";
```

the video is served with the 'content-disposition: attachment" header, to force the browser to download (instead of trying to play/open it).

Comment: Wow, a great question. I might try playing with your server settings and/or the content-disposition value. However, this might just be the single-threaded nature of this part of Chrome Incognito....who know?